# Administration tab doesn't show all the options

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We've upgraded our SonarQube server from 6.1 to 6.5 version and post upgrade we aren't able to see the administration options for any of the projects as earlier. We see only few options enabled "Quality Profile & Quality Gate". However, we can browse to each of the tabs by creating urls in the browser. Its just that the UI doesn't show these options.
[image: screenshot]

Can someone let us know what could've gone wrong and help us resolve this issue.

This would play a major role in helping the customers in managing their projects.

Comment: Can someone please help me with the question here. Has someone faced any similar issue or knows how to get the options back in UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was due to the way permissions were changed recently on our server. Global administrators group do not have administer permissions for any projects and Administer group is created for each of the enterprise projects on boarded to our server.